# How to truncate a BigInteger to int/long/uint/ulong?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

Standard casts from `BigInteger` to fixed-size integer all throw `OverflowException` if the number is too large (and [`unchecked` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214863/unchecked-block-doesnt-work-with-biginteger)).

How can I get `unchecked`-like conversion behavior?

Comment: Duplicate of [converting int to/from System.Numerics.BigInteger in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127565/converting-int-to-from-system-numerics-biginteger-in-c-sharp) (read past the first answer).

Comment: I do believe this question has value though as it could serve as a signpost to a problem that isn't asked frequently. Upvoted.

Comment: I don't think it should count as a "duplicate" when someone asks an essentially broader or different question and then a low-rated answer coincidentally supplies an answer to a more specific/different variation on that other question that could have incidentally been a reasonable answer to this question. Plus, I think you're referring to Turpin and Pedro's answers, neither of which are the correct way to truncate to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You can truncate a `BigInteger` by masking off the higher bits. For example, given a `BigInteger big`:

- Convert to `uint` with `(uint)(big & uint.MaxValue)`
- Convert to `ulong` with `(ulong)(big & ulong.MaxValue)`
- Convert to `int` with `unchecked((int)(uint)(big & uint.MaxValue))`
- Convert to `long` with `unchecked((long)(ulong)(big & ulong.MaxValue))`

This technique is not efficient; it requires two memory allocations (one to convert e.g. `uint.MaxValue` to `BigInteger`, and another to hold the result of the `&` operation). But I don't see any other way. Memory allocations are avoided, however, when the mask is smaller than 32 bits (e.g. converting to `ushort` with `(ushort)(big & ushort.MaxValue)` should not allocate memory) because `BigInteger` does not allocate memory for numbers that are 31 bits or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

A faster approach:

```
public static int ToInt(this BigInteger big) {
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(big.ToByteArray().AsSpan(0, 4)); }
```

Solutions for `long`, `uint`, etc. are straightforward.

Comment: This is as slow as the integer is big. If the `BigInteger` is 100 KB in size, for example, 100 KB are allocated and filled.

Comment: @Qwertie yes, it all depends on what data is being processed. That said, both solutions break even (speedwise) with aproximately 190 byte big integers. That is insanely big numbers... so if the average size is below that, bit masking is slower.

Comment: This throws an exception for small BigInteger values, since there are less than four bytes.